# Map Values in 'nested' association

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations, json-format

JSON often returns sort of 'nested' associations like so:

```
assoc = <|"key1" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, 
          "key2" -> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>|>
```

It is often needed to apply `f` as follows.

```
assoc = <|"key1" -> <|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> 2|>, 
          "key2" -> <|"a" -> f[3], "b" -> 4|>|>
```

I see some traditional ways, i.e. `MapAt`, but I'm searching more specific way for the  task, like `KeyValueMap` or something similar. Which one would you recommend?
(Parsing APIs results is a good example of usecase.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have failed to find a good duplicate so:

```
assoc // Query[All, {"a" -> f}]
```

or

```
MapAt[f, assoc, {All, "a"}]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
assoc = <|"key1" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, "key2" -> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>|>;
assoc[[All, "a"]] = Map[f, Values[assoc[[All, "a"]]]];
assoc
```

> <|"key1" -> <|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> 2|>, "key2" -> <|"a" -> f[3], "b" ->
>   4|>|>

Comment: Kuba's solution is much shorter (+1) but an in-place modifcation may also have its applications.